# php if variable1 is not in array or if variable1 is not variable2 then echo

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

The first part before || works on a standalone basis, but the second added (OR) second condition doesn't perform.

eg. $category="Cycle", or ($category) Cycle is not ($primaryName) Running
I would expect to echo Running;

eg $category="Surf" echo nothing;

eg $category="Tech" and $primaryName="Tech" echo nothing;

eg $category="Tech" and &primaryName="Clean" echo "Clean";

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<?php $categorycheck = array("Surf", "Sail", "Driving", "Flying");

if ((! in_array($category, $categorycheck)) || ($category != $primaryName))
{
    echo '<li>' . $primaryName . '</li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you need AND instead of OR inside your if statement.

Comment: 2 times -if not- and -or or and- or got me confused. Need a coffee! Thanks Mutale!

Answer (score 2):

Replace || with &&, otherwise it will evaluate as true every time $category is not an element of $categorycheck.

Answer (score 2):

thanks to Mutale, the working code is:

```
<?php $categorycheck = array("Surf", "Sail", "Driving", "Flying");

if ((! in_array($category, $categorycheck)) && ($category != $primaryName))
{
echo '<li>' . $primaryName . '</li>';
}
?>
```